# maven-publish with Kotlin for android aars

Tags: android, maven, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Android library that I'm trying to publish to an s3 maven repo I've set up. Everything works but I can't seem to see the sources. Here's what I have

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier 'sources'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url awsUrl
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey awsAccessKey
                secretKey awsSecretKey
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "com.example"
            artifactId = "library-0"
            version = libraryVersionName
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.name}-debug.aar")
            artifact(sourceJar)
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    if(it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

project.tasks.whenTaskAdded { addedTask ->
    if (addedTask.name == 'generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication') {
        addedTask.dependsOn assembleDebug
    }
}
```

On my app I've added the maven repo url and am including the library with:

```
implementation 'com.example:library-0:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Everything works, the app builds and the library is running great. Only issue is when I go to view the sources of any of the classes/functions I only see the function stubs saying compiled code and no javadoc. Is there something I should be doing different with the source jar?

UPDATE

I've changed the publication to `aar` and looked at my `.gradle/caches/` directory which now contains my library:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
R.txt
jars/classes.jar
res/layout/**
res/values/**
```

`jar/classes.jar` contains all the compiled `.class` files and the proguard file. During the upload I do see that I've uploaded:

```
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.aar
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.aar.md5
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.aar.sha1
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.pom
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.pom.md5
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5.pom.sha1
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5-sources.jar
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5-sources.jar.md5
library-0-1.0.0-20180306.153335-5-sources.jar.sha1
```

UPDATE

As an added reference, I found a sample of a library with similar publishing: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library-aar/1.0.1/ Here, it looks like it's the same structure with the appended `-sources`. The `.pom` file doesn't look like it needs to specify anything special. As a reference, here's my `.pom` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>library-0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre7</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
      <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>android.arch.lifecycle</groupId>
      <artifactId>extensions</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
      <artifactId>glide</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
mavenJava(MavenPublication)
```

with

```
aar(MavenPublication)
```

Comment: Didn't quite do the trick, it looks more correct, but I'm still not seeing the sources jar in my `~/.gradle/caches/moduels2/files-2.1/` directory (it's just pulling the `.aar` again.

Comment: This only changes the name of the publication, nothing to do with its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You try this gradle plugin, it is easy to publish aars or jars:

https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidMavenPushPlugin